# How do I run PHP on the server, but not using a browser?

Tags: php

I'm just starting to code with PHP, learning the basics.  So far it's just pretty standard stuff.  I'm coding & testing it locally using xampp.

When I've finished the file I'm able to FTP the .php file to a server, and run it on the server using a browser on my local PC. (eg. [www.mydomain.com/myphpfile.php](http://www.mydomain.com/myphpfile.php))

So far so good.  But what if I want the PHP script to run on the server permanently?  So it will sit there doing stuff without me needing to run it from a browser?

How do I execute it, and how do I know if it's running (given that because I'm not running it via a browser I can't see any echo text for example)?

I can't find anything obvious as everything seems to revolve around running it from a browser, or running it locally.

Comment: Explain more. what do you wanna do?

Comment: You can use a cron job to execute your php file at specific times (e.g. every minute, once per day) and then send you an email with the results.

Comment: You can SSH on your server and execute as you like.

Comment: You could potentially, if the server administrator allows, configure it to be run as a daemon (I.e. an automated service) - this is good for programs such as servers which must sit listening all the time for requests or events to happen, and then act on them (such as a webserver, for example). What do you actually need your program to do?

Comment: `how do I know if it's running `...most services log their progress and problems to a file, then you can check the file whenever you like.

Comment: What does it need to do - It needs to sit there and poll a website via its API, and if a certain event has occurred it needs to write an XML file to an FTP server.  It also needs to poll the FTP server looking for "reply" files, and if found write information to the website via the API.  Basically EDI between two incompatible 3rd party systems.  So it needs to run all the time, with no outside intervention.

Comment: Sounds like it might be ok as a cron job - write a script which runs one cycle of the process, and then set that to trigger every minute or something.